# Cassandra OOM with large RangeTombstoneList objects in memory

Tags: cassandra, out-of-memory

We have had problems with our cassandra nodes going OOM for some time, so finally we got them configured so that we could get a heap dump to try and see what was causing the OOM.

In the dump there where 16 threads (named SharedPool-Worker-XX) each executing a SliceFromReadCommand from the same table. Each of the 16 threads had a RangeTombstoneList object retaining between 200 and 240mb of memory.

The table in question are used as a queue (I know, far from the ideal use case for cassandra, but that is how it is) between two applications, where one writes and the other reads. So it is not unlikely that there is a large number of tombstones in the table...how ever I have been unable to find them.

I did a trace on the query issued against the table, and it resulted in the following:

```
cqlsh:ddp> select json_data
   ... from file_download
   ... where ti = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

 ti | uuid | json_data
----+------+-----------

(0 rows)

Tracing session: b2f2be60-01c8-11e8-ae90-fd18acdea80d

 activity                                                                                                                           | timestamp                  | source       | source_elapsed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------
                                                                                                             Execute CQL3 query | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.214000 | 10.60.73.232 |              0
 Parsing select json_data\nfrom file_download\nwhere ti = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.260000 | 10.60.73.232 |            105
                                                                                      Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.262000 | 10.60.73.232 |            197
                                                        Executing single-partition query on file_download [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.263000 | 10.60.73.232 |            442
                                                                             Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.264000 | 10.60.73.232 |            491
                                                                              Merging memtable tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.265000 | 10.60.73.232 |            517
                                                                Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 2444 [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.270000 | 10.60.73.232 |            608
                                                                   Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8 [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.271000 | 10.60.73.232 |            665
                                Skipped 0/2 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.273000 | 10.60.73.232 |            700
                                                               Merging data from memtables and 0 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.274000 | 10.60.73.232 |            707
                                                                        Read 0 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.274000 | 10.60.73.232 |            754
                                                                                                               Request complete | 2018-01-25 12:10:14.215148 | 10.60.73.232 |           1148
```

cfstats also shows avg./max tombstones pr. slice to be 0.

This makes me question whether or not the OOM was actually due to large amount of tombstones or something else?

We run cassandra v2.1.17

Comment: Can you upload the heapdump into eclipse memory analyzer https://www.eclipse.org/mat/ and post the pie chart output which shows where the maximum memory was consumed?

Comment: Pie chart doesn't show much, it just shows the 5 largest of the worker threads I mentioned, they take up a quarter of the memory.

Comment: So what’s  occupying the other 3/4 of heap?

Comment: The other 11 worker thread's RangeTombstoneList objects.